How to stop Tor from Mac terminal?
I use Tor with Safari on Mac.
Once it is installed and configured, there are two ways to start it:

Using the brew services start tor command
Using the tor command

In the former case, I can always stop it using the brew services stop tor command. But how to stop it in the latter case, given that I already closed the current terminal session, and therefore Control-C won't help?

The easiest way to stop Tor in the latter case is if you know the exact path of the Tor binary, in which case you can directly kill all instances of it with
pkill:
pkill -f /path/to/tor 


Now, the other way you can kill Tor is with a simple kill “PID”:
To find Tor’s process ID, run:
ps aux | grep tor 

Then once you have said PID, just kill it with kill 12345, for example.
If that doesn’t work, force kill it with kill -9  12345.

Are there reasons you prefer pkill instead of kill or killall?

@jsx97 pkill is for binaries, and kill is for processes, if I’m not mistaken.
